# Sessions not working, session files being written

Tags: php, session

At first, my sessions kept resetting so I wrote out a simple script to test out my sessions.

```
<?php
session_start();
// Show banner
 echo '<b>Session Support Checker</b><hr />';
 // Check if the page has been reloaded
 if(!isset($_GET['reload']) OR $_GET['reload'] != 'true') {
   // Set the message
   $_SESSION['MESSAGE'] = 'Session support enabled!<br />';
   // Give user link to check
   echo '<a href="?reload=true">Click HERE</a> to check for PHP Session Support.<br />';
  } else {
  // Check if the message has been carried on in the reload
  if(isset($_SESSION['MESSAGE'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['MESSAGE'];
   } else {
   echo 'Sorry, it appears session support is not enabled, or you PHP version is to old. <a href="? reload=false">Click HERE</a> to go back.<br />';
    }
  }
 ?>
```

Needless to say, I got "Sorry, it appears session support is not enabled..." (my php version is 5.2 if memory serves, so it's definitely not too old).  I checked my php.ini file and PHP is writing session files in the folder the php.ini file points to with what appears to be correct data, yet, I can't pass any data from one page to the other.  Anybody have any idea on what is going wrong?

Here's the pertinent part (session) of phpinfo()...

http://pastebin.com/vnv7J26T

Comment: PHP 5.2.x is pretty old at this point, its no longer receiving support. But to your question. Sessions use cookies stored on the client to link a client to a session. If anything is preventing the cookies from saving or deleting cookies, it will appear that sessions are not working.

Comment: can you run phpinfo() and see if session is enabled or not. Also check session status.

Comment: Have you a "[Session]" section in your "php.ini" ?

Comment: Sorry, it's been here and there in terms of being able to check the computer.  I tried to attach the phpinfo run off but I couldn't.  Is there anything I should be looking for???  How should I see if sessions are enabled from phpinfo???

Comment: I do have a session section in my php.ini

Comment: can you post the output of `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and add the link to the question?

Comment: Have you checked what HTTP headers get sent from the server to the client? That way, you can see if the server is even trying to set the session cookie.

Comment: vanneto:  How do I do that???